# Hive using spark standalone cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have a spark standalone cluster. The cluster have 2 workers and 1 master node. I want to run hive queries using spark as an execution engine and master node as spark master so if multiple queries run on hive at the same time the master node can assign the task to different workers. While trying to run hive query using spark master getting the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper$.main(DriverWrapper.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper.main(DriverWrapper.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SPARK_RPC_SERVER_ADDRESS
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.rpc.RpcConfiguration.<clinit>(RpcConfiguration.java:48)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.RemoteDriver.<init>(RemoteDriver.java:138)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.RemoteDriver.main(RemoteDriver.java:536)
```

Comment: What versions of everything are you using?

Comment: apache-hive version 3.1.2, apache-spark version 2.4.4

Comment: You may need to use Spark3 in order to use Hive 3

Comment: Apart from version issues what else can be the root cause for this ?

Comment: No, that's basically it. There's "no such field" because you're running a version of the code that simply doesn't have that field... Plus, last I checked, Spark execution engine isn't finalized since [there are still open issues](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started) and Tez was always recommended